# Query not working but no error occured

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update my table in SQL with the values but it doesn't send the values of the PHP variables to the table... but on the page, there's no error at all and the values were all stored into the variables. I'm new to PHP.

Here's the code I did:

```
    $query8 = "UPDATE contassessment SET test='$totTP', quiz='$totQP', asgmnt='$totAP', proj='$totPP' WHERE studID = '$stud";
    mysql_query($query8);
```

Any answer anyone?

Comment: *"theres no error at all"* - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` which you're not doing.

Comment: error reporting? never knew about it... i'll try using it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a quote at the end of your query:

```
$query8 = "UPDATE contassessment SET test='$totTP', quiz='$totQP', asgmnt='$totAP', proj='$totPP' WHERE studID = '$stud'";
mysql_query($query8);
```

You should also look into using mysqli or PDO instead of mysql. Also, make sure that the value you enter in the database are sanitized. With your current query you are vulnerable to SQL injection.

To check if an error has occured after the query, you can use mysql_error: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

But please make sure you use mysqli or PDO since mysql is deprecated.

Comment: how did i miss that..... Thank you very much for the advice! Really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem at all. Please mark the answer as "Answered" if you have fixed your problem.